# Filter by Amount in MS Access Query Text Data Type Field with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a Table the Field `[Amount]` is a text field and I need to filter between two amounts.

I changed the date type in the table and it works, but sometimes records can be lost while changing Data Types.

```
Me.Tag = "Amount Between " & CCur(Me.Text93) & " And " & CCur(Me.Text94)
Me.Child77.Report.Filter = Me.Tag
```

Comment: You convert the wrong value, as`Amount`is text, it has to be converted to a number, rgen compare to controls. `Me.Tag = "CCur(Nz(Amoun,0)t) Between " & CCur(Nz(Me.Between1.Vakue),0))`.Avoid that (and convert the field to number at table-level) as this prents the usage of an index on`Amount`. Use 'speaking' names for controls, vars, etc .... Unsing tag as filter storage can `confuse, if tag is used otherwise.

Comment: Why is Amount field text and not number type?

Comment: _sometimes records can be lost while changing Data Types._ No. You don't "just change" data type. Never.